# Security considerations with online browser-based games

Tags: javascript, web, browser, mean

I would like to get some information or at least areas to research in regards to browser based game security.

I am new to this area of development, I am working with the MEAN stack and have basic knowledge with server side security, but am looking for the correct ways and procedures to focus my research on with regards to games.

As i understand i will need the game classes and data to be server side with a vast amount of validation prior to sending down the changes back to the clients but this is where my knowledge stops. I have been researching this topic and find that I am able to find information on general video game security but not in relation to browser games.

My question is what security considerations do i need to make for an online turn based browser game.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assume that the client **lies** to you. In *everything*.

You will need to second guess everything the client sends you.

For example: Lets say the chess client sends you "The black player wants to move his rook A1 to A4"

You need to make sure

- that whoever sent this actually *is* the black player.
- It *is* their turn.
- there *is* a rook on A1 *and it is black*.
- a rook is actually allowed to make the move A1 to A4 (in this case yes, what if it was a bishop?)
- nothing is on A2 and A3 and if A4 is occupied it's a white playing piece.
- by giving up A1, the black king is not in danger of being taken by a white piece

Now, a good user interface would check all this on the client. And the users will expect that. **But** despite all those checks, the client can still in the end lie to you. Because once your code gets transferred to the client computer, the player on the other end can alter it to whatever they like.

So remember the first law of game security: **The client is in the hands of the enemy**.

Comment: This makes sense, so you are saying that i should perform checks for all the scenario's you gave on client? wouldn't that be dangerous in that they could find ways to overwrite them? I forgot to mention I am working with web sockets and each game is running through memory. I was also a bit more interested in preventing more complex game issues like handling a user being able to use the dev tools in a browser to cheat or using network lag to prevent other players taking their turn

Comment: @user3366235 That is exactly my point: *You cannot*. Your user will be able to manipulate the frontend as they wish, so you need to make sure that you don't rely on what your frontend sends you. If a user sends you a command, *make sure* it's valid. Without a concrete game it's hard to say anything specific, but basically check all the rules on both sides, the client (for convenience and user experience) and the server (to make sure nobody cheats).